# How to imitate CustomStringConvertible

Tags: swift, swift2

How do I make a protocol or type, which, when instantiated, accepts alle kinds of types like Int, Double, String, NSDate etc like CustomStringConvertible?

The first block conforms to CustomerStringConvertible and works fine.

The second block ("My way...") doesn't (which I understand, but I don't know how to solve it)

How should I implement this? I created this in an online playground (swiftStub, see http://swiftstub.com/222917135/?v=beta)

```
    print( "The CustomStringConvertible way")
    var itemToPrint : CustomStringConvertible
    itemToPrint = "Bart"
    print( itemToPrint )
    itemToPrint = 109
    print( itemToPrint )
    itemToPrint = NSDate()
    print( itemToPrint )


    print( "My way..doesnt work...what must I do to imitate CustomStringConvertible???")
    protocol AProtocol {
        var value: Double { get } 
    }

    extension Double: AProtocol {
        var value: Double { return self }
    }

    var myVarProtocol: AProtocol
    myVarProtocol=127
    print( myVarProtocol )
    myVarProtocol="Bart..THIS IS NOT ALLOWED" 
    print( myVarProtocol )
    myVarProtocol=NSDate()
    print( myVarProtocol )
```

Comment: You haven't made `String` conform to `AProtocol`...

Comment: Ok, but how should I implement this?. I need to store the string as well

Answer (score 0):

Such thing already exists in the language - [AnyObjects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342). However working with non-specific types will force you to cast it to a specific type whenever you want to call a method of the specific type.

Comment: It's not that I need to use it, I want to be able to understand and implement this.